# Apache Flink: AWS S3 timeout exception when starting a job from a savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job which has large state in a Map operator. We are taking savepoint which has around 80GB storing to AWS S3. We have around 100 parallelism for this operator. However, when we recover from the savepoint, there is always exception like

> Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Failed to open s3a://xxxx/UbfK/flink/savepoints/logjoin/savepoint-a9600e-39fd2cc07076/f9a31490-461a-42f3-88be-ec169145c35f at 0 on s3a://adshonor-data-cube-test-apse1/UbfK/flink/savepoints/logjoin/savepoint-a9600e-39fd2cc07076/f9a31490-461a-42f3-88be-ec169145c35f: org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool.

Is there a configuration parameter to increase the timeout settings for AWS S3 in Flink or another way to avoid this error?

Comment: We have tried modifying the fs.s3a.connection.maximum but it doesn't work. Timeout error still happens. We finally solve the problem temporally by reduce each taskmanager's slot number. Previously we have a few big taskmanagers which have 30-40 slots. By downgrade the machine size and reduce the slots number to 8 and increase the number of the taskmanagers, we finally eliminate the timeout errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `fs.s3a.connection.maximum` to something like 50 or 100

Answer (score 1):

to elaborate a bit on what Steve said...it's likely that the problem is the HTTP client being used doesn't have a large enough "connection pool".

> Each S3A client interacting with a single bucket, as a single user,
>   has its own dedicated pool of open HTTP 1.1 connections alongside a
>   pool of threads used for upload and copy operations. The default pool
>   sizes are intended to strike a balance between performance and
>   memory/thread use.

For a good overview of things that you can tune (which includes `fs.s3a.connection.max` see the "Options to Tune" section of [this Hadoop page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/performance.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because Flink uses AWS connection code, the setting to bump is `fs.s3.maxConnections`, which isn't the same as a pure Hadoop configuration.

When running on AWS EMR, you can refer to this document: https://aws.amazon.com/cn/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-timeout-connection-wait/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this - according to the [Flink documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-plugins)

> For example, Hadoop has a fs.s3a.connection.maximum configuration key. If you want to change it, you need to put s3.connection.maximum: xyz to the flink-conf.yaml. Flink will internally translate this back to fs.s3a.connection.maximum.

So to set the value for maximum connections you actually want to put `s3.connection.maximum: xyz` (or `s3a.connection.maximum: xyz` which worked for me) in your Flink config to change this value.